# How to add IGNORECASE without Compiling a RE

Tags: python

Instead of using:

```
var = re.compile('old word',re.IGNORECASE)
```

And then using:

```
var2 = var.sub(r'new word', line)
```

How would I implement `IGNORECASE` into:

```
var = re.sub(r'WoRd',r'Word',line)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `flags` kwarg:

```
re.sub(r'WoRd',r'Word',line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Note that it's only available in 2.7 or later.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flags in re.sub() too, like this:

```
var = re.sub(r'WoRd',r'Word',line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

the [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function accepts a `flags` argument:

```
var = re.sub(r'WoRd', r'Word', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `flags=` in the `re.sub()` call, you can also simply add `(?i)` to the beginning of the regular expression.